# Sum elements of an array, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm just trying to see if the elements of my array are divisible by the sum, I think something is wrong with my for-loop that sums up the elements of the array, any tips on how I should proceed?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int apa[] = {3,3,3};
     System.out.print(allEqual(apa));

 }
 public static boolean allEqual(int[] a) {
    int summa = 0;
    boolean svar = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        summa +=a[i];

    }
    if (summa % a.length == 0) {
        return svar;
    } else {
        svar = false;
        return svar;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening that you don't expect? We can't read your mind!

Comment: Well it doesn't work at all, I get this error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"

Comment: When you get an error you should tell us about it (in the question).

Comment: Your function will return true for the array {1,2,3}  Should it really be named allEqual() if you are actually testing for an integer mean?

Comment: You're right it shouldn't I didn't originally intend to check for an integer mean but to see if all the integers were equal. I am going to modify my code now and see if I can try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int apa[] = {3,3,3};
     System.out.print(allEqual(apa));

 }
 public static boolean allEqual(int[] a) {
    int summa = 0;
    boolean svar = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // <-- HERE
// if i == a.length, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be raised
        summa +=a[i];

    }
    if (summa % a.length == 0) {
        return svar;
    } else {
        svar = false;
        return svar;
    }

}
```

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat This is the original code with the marked line changed.

Comment: @JasonC I know, but that's not obvious.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat better now?

Answer (score 6):

Array indexes in Java range from `0` through `length - 1`, so for your array of length `3`, the maximum index is `2`.  Stop your `for` loop before you get to `length`, or else you'll run off the end of the array with `a[3]` and you'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you have observed.  Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks that's it! that equals sign ruined everything.

Answer (score 5):

You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++)
```

You probably mean:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

As accessing `a[a.length]` will always lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (valid index range is *[0, a.length-1]*).

You could also use this syntax to eliminate the possibility of that mistake, if you don't actually need to do anything with the index itself in the loop:

```
for (int value : a)
    summa += value;
```

All of this, of course, assumes `a != null`.